# Adding gridlines using Cartopy

Tags: matplotlib, cartopy

I'm trying to add gridlines to a map I made using Cartopy, however, when I use the example code from the cartopy documentation, it doesn't display what I want and I can't figure out how to manipulate it to do so.

```
def plotMap():

    proj = ccrs.Mercator(central_longitude=180, min_latitude=15, 
    max_latitude=55)

    fig, ax = plt.subplots(subplot_kw=dict(projection=proj), figsize=(12,12))

    ax.set_extent([255 ,115, 0, 60], crs=ccrs.PlateCarree())

    ax.add_feature(cfeature.LAND, facecolor='0.3')
    ax.add_feature(cfeature.LAKES, alpha=0.9)  
    ax.add_feature(cfeature.BORDERS, zorder=10)
    ax.add_feature(cfeature.COASTLINE, zorder=10)


    #(http://www.naturalearthdata.com/features/)
    states_provinces = cfeature.NaturalEarthFeature(
            category='cultural',  name='admin_1_states_provinces_lines',
            scale='50m', facecolor='none')
    ax.add_feature(states_provinces, edgecolor='black', zorder=10)

    #ax.gridlines(xlocs=grids_ma, ylocs=np.arange(-80,90,20), zorder=21, 
    draw_labels=True ) 
    ax.gridlines(crs=ccrs.PlateCarree(), linewidth=2, color='black', 
    draw_labels=True, alpha=0.5, linestyle='--')
    ax.xlabels_top = False
    ax.ylabels_left = False
    ax.ylabels_right=True
    ax.xlines = True
    ax.xlocator = mticker.FixedLocator([-160, -140, -120, 120, 140, 160, 180,])
    ax.xformatter = LONGITUDE_FORMATTER
    ax.yformatter = LATITUDE_FORMATTER
    ax.xlabel_style = {'size': 15, 'color': 'gray'}
    ax.xlabel_style = {'color': 'red', 'weight': 'bold'}


    return fig, ax
```

I've attached a picture of the output. For reference, I only want the longitude gridlines to start at the left of my domain and end at the right side, preferably being spaced every 20 degrees. Ideally the same for latitude lines as well. 
[Bad gridline plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NxbFT.png)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

**Update: Cartopy's gridliner dateline issue noted below has been fixed at some point, so either of the below code solutions should now give the desired outcome.**

Is the example you are following the one at the bottom of [this page](http://scitools.org.uk/cartopy/docs/latest/matplotlib/gridliner.html)?  If so, you are attempting to set attributes on the GeoAxes (`ax`) instance which should be set on the GridLiner (`gl`) instance:

```
import cartopy
import cartopy.crs as ccrs
import cartopy.feature as cfeature
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.ticker as mticker

from cartopy.mpl.gridliner import LONGITUDE_FORMATTER, LATITUDE_FORMATTER

def plotMap():    
    proj = ccrs.Mercator(central_longitude=180, min_latitude=15, 
    max_latitude=55)

    fig, ax = plt.subplots(subplot_kw=dict(projection=proj), figsize=(12,12))

    ax.set_extent([255 ,115, 0, 60], crs=ccrs.PlateCarree())

    ax.add_feature(cfeature.LAND, facecolor='0.3')
    ax.add_feature(cfeature.LAKES, alpha=0.9)  
    ax.add_feature(cfeature.BORDERS, zorder=10)
    ax.add_feature(cfeature.COASTLINE, zorder=10)

    states_provinces = cfeature.NaturalEarthFeature(
            category='cultural',  name='admin_1_states_provinces_lines',
            scale='50m', facecolor='none')
    ax.add_feature(states_provinces, edgecolor='black', zorder=10)   
    
    gl = ax.gridlines(crs=ccrs.PlateCarree(), linewidth=2, color='black', alpha=0.5, linestyle='--', draw_labels=True)
    gl.xlabels_top = False
    gl.ylabels_left = False
    gl.ylabels_right=True
    gl.xlines = True
    gl.xlocator = mticker.FixedLocator([120, 140, 160, 180, -160, -140, -120])
    gl.ylocator = mticker.FixedLocator([0, 20, 40, 60])
    gl.xformatter = LONGITUDE_FORMATTER
    gl.yformatter = LATITUDE_FORMATTER
    gl.xlabel_style = {'color': 'red', 'weight': 'bold'}
```

This produces the following map.  The gridliner doesn't seem to be coping with the dateline. I do not know if there is a way around this, but there is a note at the top of the above linked documentation to say that there are currently known limitations with this class, so maybe not.

[image]

An alternative is to set the various labels and their styles directly with matplotlib.  Note that you have to set the ticklabels separately from the ticks, otherwise you get labels corresponding to the Mercator coordinate reference system:

```
import cartopy.mpl.ticker as cticker

def plotMap2():
    proj = ccrs.Mercator(central_longitude=180, min_latitude=15, 
    max_latitude=55)

    fig, ax = plt.subplots(subplot_kw=dict(projection=proj), figsize=(12,12))

    ax.set_extent([255 ,115, 0, 60], crs=ccrs.PlateCarree())

    ax.add_feature(cfeature.LAND, facecolor='0.3')
    ax.add_feature(cfeature.LAKES, alpha=0.9)  
    ax.add_feature(cfeature.BORDERS, zorder=10)
    ax.add_feature(cfeature.COASTLINE, zorder=10)

    states_provinces = cfeature.NaturalEarthFeature(
            category='cultural',  name='admin_1_states_provinces_lines',
            scale='50m', facecolor='none')
    ax.add_feature(states_provinces, edgecolor='black', zorder=10)

    ax.set_xticks([120., 140., 160., 180., -160., -140., -120.], crs=ccrs.PlateCarree())
    ax.set_xticklabels([120., 140., 160., 180., -160., -140., -120.], color='red', weight='bold')
    ax.set_yticks([20, 40], crs=ccrs.PlateCarree())
    ax.set_yticklabels([20, 40])
    ax.yaxis.tick_right()
    
    lon_formatter = cticker.LongitudeFormatter()
    lat_formatter = cticker.LatitudeFormatter()
    ax.xaxis.set_major_formatter(lon_formatter)
    ax.yaxis.set_major_formatter(lat_formatter)
    ax.grid(linewidth=2, color='black', alpha=0.5, linestyle='--')
```

[image]

Comment: Wow this is great! This is exactly what I wanted. Thanks so much.