# Inscribing a smaller domain onto a cartopy map in Python

Tags: python, matplotlib, shapely, cartopy

I've been working to make a visual for a poster regarding the physical domain that I am studying. I'm working with a nested domain, so I have 1 smaller domain inside a larger outer domain. I'm trying to create a cartopy plot that shows both the outer domain and inner domain. Ideally, the result would look something like this:[image: Inner domain in an outer domain.]

I'm really struggling with trying to get my smaller domain inscribed onto my map. I've attempted to make a Shapely LinearRing to show the inner domain, but it is not working. Here's the code I have created so far:

```
# Imports
import numpy as np
import sys, os
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
%matplotlib inline
import netCDF4
from netCDF4 import Dataset
from matplotlib.cm import get_cmap
import cartopy.crs as ccrs
import cartopy.feature as cfeature
from cartopy.feature import NaturalEarthFeature, COLORS
import metpy as mp
import metpy.calc as mpcalc
from metpy.calc import divergence, smooth_gaussian
from metpy.units import units
import xarray as xr
from wrf import getvar, interplevel, to_np, latlon_coords, get_cartopy, cartopy_xlim, cartopy_ylim, ALL_TIMES
from shapely.geometry.polygon import LinearRing
from cartopy.mpl.ticker import LongitudeFormatter, LatitudeFormatter
from shapely import geometry

# Get 1km lats/lons
lats1km = getvar(ds1, 'lat')
lons1km = getvar(ds1, 'lon')
lat1km_max = to_np(np.max(lats1km))
lat1km_min = to_np(np.min(lats1km))
lon1km_max = to_np(np.max(lons1km))
lon1km_min = to_np(np.min(lons1km))

# Get 3km lats/lons
lats3km = getvar(ds3, 'lat')
lons3km = getvar(ds3, 'lon')
lat3km_max = to_np(np.max(lats3km))
lat3km_min = to_np(np.min(lats3km))
lon3km_max = to_np(np.max(lons3km))
lon3km_min = to_np(np.min(lons3km))

domain = [lon3km_min, lat3km_min, lon3km_max, lat3km_max]
lons = [lat1km_min, lat1km_min, lat1km_max, lat1km_max]
lats = [lon1km_min, lon1km_max, lon1km_max, lon1km_min]
ring = LinearRing(list(zip(lons, lats)))
geom = geometry.box(minx=lon1km_min, miny=lat1km_min, maxx=lon1km_max, maxy=lat1km_max)

# Grab CRS
crs = get_cartopy(wrfin=ds1)

# Create figure and axes
fig = plt.figure(figsize=(20,10))
ax0 = fig.add_subplot(1, 1, 1, projection=crs)
ax0.set_extent([lon3km_min, lon3km_max, lat3km_min, lat3km_max])
ax0.add_geometries([ring], crs=crs, facecolor='blue', edgecolor='black')
ax0.add_geometries([geom], crs=crs, alpha=0.3)

plot_background(ax0)
```

This yields my outer domain, but not my inner domain:
[image: Outer domain, but no inner domain]

What am I doing wrong, and what can I do to get my inner domain shown on the map? Thank you for the help! I really appreciate it!

NOTE: I have already attempted the solution in [this link.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55303911/add-polygon-box-to-cartopy-python) I am still unable to visualize my polygon.

Comment: Please include your imports.  Its pretty impossible to know what `geometry` is, for instance.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Add polygon box to cartopy python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55303911/add-polygon-box-to-cartopy-python)

Comment: @JodyKlymak I have added my imports. Also, I have already incorporated that link in this program without using them as functions. Still not able to get my inner domain.

Comment: Try to create something self-contained we can work with.  We don't have your data, nor your `plot_background` function.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at [EOmaps](https://github.com/raphaelquast/EOmaps) ! (I'm the dev)   it provides simple functions to add static (or interactive) indicators such as projected rectangles or ellipses to cartopy plots in 1 line!

```py
from eomaps import Maps
m = Maps()
m.add_coastlines()

props = dict(xy=(10, 45), xy_crs=4326, radius_crs=4326, shape="rectangles")

m.add_marker(**props, radius=3, fc=(0,1,0,.5), ec="r", lw=2)
m.add_marker(**props, radius=5, fc="none", ec="k")
m.add_marker(**props, radius=(15, 10), fc="none", ec="m", ls="--", lw=2)

m.figure.ax.set_extent((-15., 65., -5., 75.))
```

[image]