# White line appearing on map with python plt.contourf

Tags: python, maps, contourf

I'm using this code to plot aerosols maps.

```
region = Box(
    Box_name="Focus",
    lonmin = -136,
    lonmax = 20,
    latmin = 20,
    latmax = 70
)

Box1 = Box(
    Box_name="Box 1",
    lonmin = -124,
    lonmax = -114,
    latmin = 35,
    latmax = 42
)
Box2 =  Box(
        Box_name="Box 2",
        lonmin=-124,
        lonmax=-114,
        latmin=43,
        latmax=50
)
Box3 =  Box(
        Box_name="Box 3",
        lonmin=-104,
        lonmax=-94,
        latmin=42,
        latmax=49
)
Box4 =  Box(
        Box_name="Box 4",
        lonmin=-88,
        lonmax=-78,
        latmin=40,
        latmax=47
)
Box5 =  Box(
        Box_name="Box 5",
        lonmin=-65,
        lonmax=-55,
        latmin=43,
        latmax=50
)

def plot_geog_location(region, lakes=False, borders=False, rivers=False):
    """ use cartopy to plot the region (defined as a namedtuple object)

    Arguments:
    ---------
    : region (Region namedtuple)
        region of interest bounding box defined in engineering/regions.py
    : lakes (bool)
        show lake features
    : borders (bool)
        show lake features
    : rivers (bool)
        show river features (@10m scale from NaturalEarth)
    """
    lonmin,lonmax,latmin,latmax = region.lonmin,region.lonmax,region.latmin,region.latmax
    ax = plt.figure().gca(projection=cartopy.crs.PlateCarree())
    CS = plt.contourf(lons, lats, AOD[:,:],levels=level, extend='both',cmap=plt.cm.Oranges, norm=norm)
    plt.title('AOD mean over North America 13 to 17 Sep 2020 (Inj25)',fontsize=16)
    plt.gcf().set_size_inches(15, 11)
    cbar = plt.colorbar(CS, shrink=0.45,ticks=[0,0.25,0.5])
    cbar.ax.set_yticklabels(['0','0.25', '0.5'])
    ax.add_feature(cpf.COASTLINE)
    ax.add_feature(cfeature.STATES, zorder=1, linewidth=1, edgecolor='k',linestyle=':')
    if borders:
        ax.add_feature(cpf.BORDERS, linestyle='--')

    ax.set_extent([lonmin, lonmax, latmin, latmax])

    # plot the lat lon labels
    # https://scitools.org.uk/cartopy/docs/v0.15/examples/tick_labels.html
    # https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49956355/adding-gridlines-using-cartopy
    xticks = np.linspace(lonmin, lonmax, 5)
    yticks = np.linspace(latmin, latmax, 5)

    ax.set_xticks(xticks, crs=cartopy.crs.PlateCarree())
    ax.set_yticks(yticks, crs=cartopy.crs.PlateCarree())
    lon_formatter = LongitudeFormatter(zero_direction_label=True)
    lat_formatter = LatitudeFormatter()
    ax.xaxis.set_major_formatter(lon_formatter)
    ax.yaxis.set_major_formatter(lat_formatter)

    fig = plt.gcf()

    return fig, ax


def plot_polygon(ax, Box1, Box2, Box3, Box4, Box5):
    """
    https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/scitools-iris/LxR0EbQolyE
    Note:
    ----
    order is important:
        lower-left, upper-left, upper-right, lower-right
        2 -- 3
        |    |
        1 -- 4
    """
    ax = fig.axes[0]
    lons = [Box1.latmin, Box1.latmin, Box1.latmax, Box1.latmax]
    lats = [Box1.lonmin, Box1.lonmax, Box1.lonmax, Box1.lonmin]
    ring = LinearRing(list(zip(lons, lats)))
    lons2 = [Box2.latmin, Box2.latmin, Box2.latmax, Box2.latmax]
    lats2 = [Box2.lonmin, Box2.lonmax, Box2.lonmax, Box2.lonmin]
    ring2 = LinearRing(list(zip(lons2, lats2)))
    lons3 = [Box3.latmin, Box3.latmin, Box3.latmax, Box3.latmax]
    lats3 = [Box3.lonmin, Box3.lonmax, Box3.lonmax, Box3.lonmin]
    ring3 = LinearRing(list(zip(lons3, lats3)))
    lons4 = [Box4.latmin, Box4.latmin, Box4.latmax, Box4.latmax]
    lats4 = [Box4.lonmin, Box4.lonmax, Box4.lonmax, Box4.lonmin]
    ring4 = LinearRing(list(zip(lons4, lats4)))
    lons5 = [Box5.latmin, Box5.latmin, Box5.latmax, Box5.latmax]
    lats5 = [Box5.lonmin, Box5.lonmax, Box5.lonmax, Box5.lonmin]
    ring5 = LinearRing(list(zip(lons5, lats5)))
    ax.add_geometries([ring], cartopy.crs.PlateCarree(), facecolor='b', edgecolor='black', alpha=0.5)
    return ax


def add_sub_region_box(ax, box1, box2, box3, box4, box5):
    """ """
    geom = geometry.box(minx=Box1.lonmin,maxx=Box1.lonmax,miny=Box1.latmin,maxy=Box1.latmax)
    geom2 = geometry.box(minx=Box2.lonmin,maxx=Box2.lonmax,miny=Box2.latmin,maxy=Box2.latmax)
    geom3 = geometry.box(minx=Box3.lonmin,maxx=Box3.lonmax,miny=Box3.latmin,maxy=Box3.latmax)
    geom4 = geometry.box(minx=Box4.lonmin,maxx=Box4.lonmax,miny=Box4.latmin,maxy=Box4.latmax)
    geom5 = geometry.box(minx=Box5.lonmin,maxx=Box5.lonmax,miny=Box5.latmin,maxy=Box5.latmax)
    ax.add_geometries([geom], crs=cartopy.crs.PlateCarree(), alpha=0.3)
    ax.add_geometries([geom2], crs=cartopy.crs.PlateCarree(), alpha=0.3)
    ax.add_geometries([geom3], crs=cartopy.crs.PlateCarree(), alpha=0.3)
    ax.add_geometries([geom4], crs=cartopy.crs.PlateCarree(), alpha=0.3)
    ax.add_geometries([geom5], crs=cartopy.crs.PlateCarree(), alpha=0.3)
    return ax


fig, ax = plot_geog_location(region,borders=True, lakes=False, rivers=False)
add_sub_region_box(ax, Box1, Box2, Box3, Box4, Box5)
```

I often got a white line appearing, looks like it's mostly on 0° latitude. Also, it's not from datas as in many other situations I don't have any white line with the same code... Any solution for that ? [image]

(It says my post is mostly code but my question is pretty clear like that I believe, I don't know what else to add to it so I'm writing a couple line to post)

Thank you,

Comment: What if you use pcolormesh (https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.pcolormesh.html) instead of contourf? If you share the data it would be easier to reproduce your problem.

Comment: Unfortunatly those are confidential modeled datas so I can't share them. But I'll try with pcolormesh and post it or close the subject if it works.
Thank you

Comment: There are multiple ways to produce a test dataset with the same structure, you could for example multiply your data by a random variable. Remember that you'll get much better answers here on SO if you provide a minimum reproducible example!

Comment: It actually was a dataset problem. Seems like there is a bug in my model that doesn't produce any data at 0 latitude... I'm sorry about that.